# PyImport_Import segmentation fault after reading in TSV with C++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, segmentation-fault

I am using C++ as a wrapper around a Python module. First, I read in a TSV file, cast it as a numpy array, import my Python module, and then pass the numpy array to Python for further analysis. When I first wrote the program, I was testing everything using a randomly generated array, and it worked well. However, once I replaced the randomly generated array with the imported TSV array, I got a segmentation fault when I tried to import the Python module. Here is some of my code:

```
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN

#include <python3.8/Python.h>
#include "./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 0);

    Py_Initialize();
    import_array();

    static const int numberRows = 1000;
    static const int numberColumns = 500;

    npy_intp dims[2]{ numberRows, numberColumns };

    static const int numberDims = 2;

    double(*c_arr)[numberColumns]{ new double[numberRows][numberColumns] };

    // *********************************************************** 
    // THIS PART OF THE CODE GENERATES A RANDOM ARRAY AND WORKS WITH THE REST OF THE CODE
    // // initialize random number generation
    // typedef std::mt19937 MyRNG;
    // std::random_device r;
    // MyRNG rng{r()};
    // std::lognormal_distribution<double> lognormalDistribution(1.6, 0.25);

    // //populate array
    // for (int i=0; i < numberRows; i++) {
    //     for (int j=0; j < numberColumns; j++) {
    //         c_arr[i][j] = lognormalDistribution(rng);
    //     }
    // }
    // ***********************************************************

    // *********************************************************** 
    // THIS PART OF THE CODE INGESTS AN ARRAY FROM TSV AND CAUSES CODE TO FAIL AT PyImport_Import
    std::ifstream data("data.mat");
    std::string line;
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    while (std::getline(data, line)) {
        std::stringstream lineStream(line);
        std::string cell;
        while (std::getline(lineStream, cell, '\t')) {
            c_arr[row][column] = std::stod(cell);
            column++;
        }
        row++;
        column = 0;
        if (row > numberRows) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // *********************************************************** 

    PyArrayObject *npArray = reinterpret_cast<PyArrayObject*>(
        PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(numberDims, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, reinterpret_cast<void*>(c_arr))
        );

    const char *moduleName = "cpp_test";
    PyObject *pname = PyUnicode_FromString(moduleName);

    // ***********************************************************
    // CODE FAILS HERE - SEGMENTATION FAULT
    PyObject *pyModule = PyImport_Import(pname);


    // .......
    // THERE IS MORE CODE BELOW NOT INCLUDED HERE
}
```

So, I'm not sure why the code fails when ingest data from a TSV file, but not when I use randomly generated data.

EDIT: (very stupid mistake incoming) I used the conditional `row > numberRows` for the stopping condition in the `while` loop and so this affected the row number used for the final line in the array. Once I changed that conditional to `row == numberRows`, everything worked. Who knew being specific about rows when building an array was so important? I'll leave this up as a testament to stupid programming mistakes and maybe someone will learn a little something from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you don't have to use arrays for storing the information(like double values) in 2D manner because you can also use dynamically sized containers like `std::vector` as shown below. The **advantage** of using `std::vector` is that you don't have to know the number of rows and columns beforehand in your input file(data.mat). So you don't have to allocate memory beforehand for rows and columns. You can add the values dynamically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<fstream>
int main() {
    std::string line;
    double word;

    
    std::ifstream inFile("data.mat");
    
    //create/use a std::vector instead of builit in array 
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
    
    if(inFile)
    {
        while(getline(inFile, line, '\n'))        
        {
            //create a temporary vector that will contain all the columns
            std::vector<double> tempVec;
            
            
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            
            //read word by word(or double by double) 
            while(ss >> word)
            {
                //std::cout<<"word:"<<word<<std::endl;
                //add the word to the temporary vector 
                tempVec.push_back(word);
            
            }      
            
            //now all the words from the current line has been added to the temporary vector 
            vec.emplace_back(tempVec);
        }    
    }
    
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file cannot be opened"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    inFile.close();
    
    //lets check out the elements of the 2D vector so the we can confirm if it contains all the right elements(rows and columns)
    for(std::vector<double> &newvec: vec)
    {
        for(const double &elem: newvec)
        {
            std::cout<<elem<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/NcvOyf7bG). Since you didn't provide `data.mat` file, i created an example data.mat file and used it in my program which can be found at the above mentioned link.